# Problems in casting variables

Tags: java, type-mismatch

I am trying to construct an object using the following constructor in Java:

```
public UnaryNumberContract(Comparable<Number> expectedValue, Operations operator, Invariant inv) {
  super(inv, operator);
  this.expectedValue = expectedValue;
}
```

I am passing on the following parameters:

```
Comparable<Number> zero = new Integer(0); 
UnaryNumberContract contract = new UnaryNumberContract(zero, Operations.NOT_EQUALS, (Invariant) inv);
```

And I keep getting a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to Comparable<Number>`

I've checked and Number is a super class of Integer, so I don't quite understand what is goinh wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112343/java-integer-obj-cant-cast-to-comparable

Comment: Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace references to `Comparable<Number>` with `Comparable<? extends Number>`, that will solve the issue.

Also, see this [When do Java generics require <? extends T> instead of <T> and is there any downside of switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-downs)

Comment: I was avoiding generics, but went with it anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Integer` does not implement `Comparable<Number>`, it implements `Comparable<Integer>`.

`Comparable<Integer>` does not inherit from `Comparable<Number>` and this is why it's not possible to cast it.

What you can do is use `Number` for your parameter type. `Integer` does inherit `Number` and you will not have the same problem.

Comment: @Tiago I included a workaround. Use `Number` instead of `Comparable<Number>` for your parameter type.

Comment: It isn't really a problem, you are correctly getting an error based on how the Integer class is defined.

Comment: Thainks. I can cast `Number` to `Comparable<Number>` within the constructor then?

Comment: @Tiago: No: Number doesn't implement Comparable (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/480632/771837 for a fairly good rationale). Nitin's answer to your question should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `Integer` doesn't implement `Comparable<Number>` it is an implements `Comparable<Integer>`.

> All Implemented Interfaces:
>   Serializable, Comparable<Integer>

[Relevant Integer JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).